# RS232 communication problem in Java

Tags: java, serial-port

Can I found out in Java if cable is pluged in RS232 port on my comp? I work on some application, I have convertor from usb to rs232 on com6 port and I need info if there is cable pluged in or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open the that the Port "COM6" at regular interval, but be careful to put it inside try-catch.

Thanks:)